# I am Struck at last step on how to add custom api key to tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online

[I am struck here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit/blob/master/documentation/tenant-settings.md#UPSCustomProperty) and i dont understand on how to add the API key using powershell as i am using sharepoint online

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run SharePoint Online Management Shell [Click here for help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps)
2. Connect to you sharepoint online environement with UID and password
3. Install Sharepointpnp power shell module using this `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`
4. RUN

   > Invoke-Expression (New-Object
   >   Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharepoint/PnP-PowerShell/master/Samples/Modules.Install/Install-SharePointPnPPowerShell.p
   >   s1')
5. Update module using `Update-Module -force`
6. `Set-PnPStorageEntity -Key "PnP-Portal-AlphaVantage-API-Key" -Value "API KEY"` -Comment "API Key for Alpha Advantage REST Stock service" -Description "API Key for Alpha Advantage
   REST Stock service"